# Elastic query - SSL error

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssl, azure-sql-database

I am stuck with the same situation mentioned here in this URL.[See SO question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994234/azure-sql-database-elastic-query-to-azure-vm-sql-instance-ssl-error)
. I am having a `Azure VM` and `Sql Azure db`. From `Sql Azure Db` i am using external table to query `Azure VM Sql` but with  error:

> The underlying error message received was: 'A connection was
>   successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred
>   during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The
>   certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)'.

I knew its a CA certificate error. But I cant purchase certificate as of now. So I wanted to if i can use self signed certificate for the same.

I am having a certificate in my Azure VM. See below in screenshot. Will it work? Do I need to install that in my Sql Azure Db too?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Azure SQL Database elastic queries they can only be created between Azure SQL databases. You will find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview).

Linked servers to SQL Azure databases are now supported as demonstrated [here](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0016.htm).

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo